# Why i'm getting this error when i use sum(n1,n2) but i get no error when i use n1+n2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def makes_twenty(n1,n2):
    return sum(n1,n2)
makes_twenty(20,10)
```

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-65c96a963589> in <module>
      1 # Check
----> 2 makes_twenty(20,10)

<ipython-input-35-9571a81855ca> in makes_twenty(n1, n2)
      1 def makes_twenty(n1,n2):
----> 2     return sum(n1,n2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `sum` accept `iterable` as an argument.

Comment: The `sum` function in Python sums an iterable, that is, for instance, a list of integers, but it won't work with two integers not placed in a list or an iterable. What would work would for instance be `sum([n1, n2])`.

Answer (score 5):

`sum` expects an iterable, for example a list or tuple.

```
>>> sum([1, 2])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty descriptive: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) accepts an iterable and returns the sum of its elements. You can call `sum((n1, n2))` if you really want to use to sum up a known amount of numbers.